I Observe Few TC Getting Failed in Selenium due to Change Password Popup Any Solution for it?
I Observe Few TC Getting Failed in Smoke Execution due to this Below Pop Up Any One Else Getting the Same Issue ?
Already Added Below Code but it didn't Work for Me
options.setExperimentalOption("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
enter image description here
options.setExperimentalOption("credentials_enable_service", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
